# How do I pause other youtube videos on page when I start playing a new one?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Im trying to solve an issue I have on my page built with Elementor. I have 3 sections with a Video player widget in each that play youtube videos. I want the videos to pause when I start playing a new one. How do I achieve this?